# What's the shortest way to check if a variable is not equal to several other variables?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I want to abbreviate this:

```
data.urlPath !== '#profile' && data.urlPath !== '#communities' && data.urlPath !== '#other'
```

to something like:

```
data.urlPath !== '#profile' || '#communities' || '#other'
// this doesn't work
```

is this possible?

Comment: I do `['#profile' ,' #other', '#...'].includes(data.urlPath) ?  action : otherAction`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`['#profile', '#communities','#other'].includes(data.urlPath)`

Comment: The above condition of cause still needs to be negated in order to match the OP's requirement.